# Custom Push Notification coming twice using Parse.com and Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, notifications

I am working in custom push notification using parse.com android. Push is successfully integrated in my application, but the problem is I am getting two notifications at a time.

One from my custom Receiver with image and other one default notification from OS without any image and that notification is not even removing from notification bar, if I am removing it, it is coming again and again on notification tray. I will paste my code snippet and images below as well.

```
// My Custom Receiver Class

public class CustomPushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    private final String TAG = CustomPushReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

    private Intent parseIntent;

    public CustomPushReceiver() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushReceive(context, intent);

        if (intent == null)
            return;
            parseIntent = intent;
        try {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
            if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE")) {
//                NOTIFICATION_ID++;
                String title = "DW";
                if (json.has("alert"))
                {
                    String text = json.getString("alert");
                    generateNotification(context, title, json, text,parseIntent);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
 }

    @Override
    protected void onPushDismiss(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushDismiss(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushOpen(context, intent);
    }

   private void generateNotification(Context context, String title, JSONObject json, String text, Intent intent) {
//        Intent intent = new Intent(context, home.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationManager mNotifM = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.log_pic_small)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.log_pic))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(text)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(text))
                        .setTicker(text)
                        .setLights(Color.GREEN, 500, 500);
        mNotifM.cancel(0);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotifM.notify(110, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Manifest file

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.restaurant.services.CustomPushReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!-- IMPORTANT: Change "info.androidhive.parsenotifications" to match your app's package name. -->
                <category android:name="com.dw" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

[image]

Comment: make sure is server sending the notifications twice or not.

Comment: Server is sending push only one time. @MuhammadBabar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is generated by the method `super.onPushReceive(context, intent);` in your `public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)`.

I think you should override `protected void onPushReceive(Context context,Intent intent)` and handle the push notification there.
NOTE: DO NOT CALL super if you override `onPushReceive` because it will display again the push.

As per Parse documentation:

> Called when the push notification is received. By default, a broadcast
>   intent will be sent if an "action" is present in the data and a
>   notification will be show if "alert" and "title" are present in the
>   data.

**EDIT**

public class CustomPushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    ..... init code here from your exaple....

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  super.onReceive(Context context, Intent intent);
}
@Override
public void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //NO SUPER CALL
  ....exact code from your onReceive.....
}
... rest of the code from your example...
```

}

I think you can handle it from here.

Comment: thanks for your answer here. Can you put a small code snippet here, so i can understand it easily. I have little bit confusion to understand it right now.

Comment: thanks alot. It solved my problem. You were right i was doing a mistake by calling super for onPushReceive, it was calling it again and again. Thats why another notification was also coming there.

Comment: @danypata. Can you help me? Please

Comment: @jojo What can I do for you ? This answer is super old :)

Comment: @danypata.I have a question like this.Thank's a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52235660/10211127

Answer (score 2):

Don't generate notification each and every time instead initialize is for the first time on your application launch

CustomPushReceiver customReciever = new CustomPushReceiver (getApplicationContext());

//set this RECIEVER to your push factory

getPushManager().setNotificationFactory(customReciever );

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have added Two receivers in Manifest file, one for default parse receiver and other for your custom receiver. If it is so, remove the parse default receiver and keep yours only.