# Android- App does not receive push notifications from parse platform

Tags: android, firebase, parse-platform, push-notification

I am using from parse platform but I can't receive any notification on my device android.

Here is my `manifest`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="lib.finder.ir.deletme">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <service
            android:name="com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseInstanceIdService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_message" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

My `App.java`:

```
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


        // Use for monitoring Parse OkHttp traffic
        // Can be Level.BASIC, Level.HEADERS, or Level.BODY
        // See http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/logging-interceptor/ to see the options.
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        builder.networkInterceptors().add(httpLoggingInterceptor);


        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                .applicationId("1")
                // if defined
                .clientKey("1")
                .server("http://1:80/parse/")
                .clientBuilder(builder)
                .build()
        );

        Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);

        // Save the current Installation to Parse.
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.i("log", "A: successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                } else {
                    Log.i("log", "B: failed to subscribe for push", e);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And `GetPush.java`:

```
public class GetPush extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushReceive(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushOpen(context, intent);
    }
}
```

And I get `google-services.json` then add to my project.

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "344518768459",
    "firebase_url": "https://parsetest-f7e60.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "parsetest-f7e60",
    "storage_bucket": "parsetest-f7e60.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:344518768459:android:a36a6a64540561a3",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "lib.finder.ir.deletme"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "344518768459-09g2pnfhscijt01e4ee8hr02mqaovurh.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyBZg-xc8vq5Eu2OJQIaDTbe91W5l5XA1eA"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 2
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Add below code on **Manifest** file,

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    <service android:name="com.parse.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.parse.fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java** file

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public static String FCMTAG = "FCM Message";
    public static String FCMSTATE = "FCMSTATE";

    JSONObject jsonObject;

    public MyFirebaseMessagingService() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageSent(String s) {
        Log.v("Fcm", "MyFirebaseMessagingService :: onMessageSent  " + s);
        super.onMessageSent(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        try {
            if (remoteMessage != null && remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
                RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
                if (notification.getTitle() != null && notification.getBody() != null) {
                    String title = notification.getTitle();
                    String message = notification.getBody();
                    Log.d("FCM", "Title: " + title + " , Message: " + message);
                    showStatusBarNotification(title, message);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("FCM", "Error : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void showStatusBarNotification(String title, String sendMessage) {
       //Code to show Push notification on Toolbar
    }

}
```

**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java** file

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "Fcm";
    Context context;
    String token;

    public MyFirebaseInstanceIDService() {
    }

    public MyFirebaseInstanceIDService(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        onTokenRefresh();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.v(TAG, "MyFirebaseInstanceIDService: Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    }


    public String getToken(){
        return token;
    }

}
```

Now You need to init **MyFirebaseInstanceIDService** on your `onCreate` function of Activity page to generate the push token,

```
new MyFirebaseInstanceIDService(ShopLoginActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:exported="false"` from below service.

```
     <service
        android:name="com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Might be from Firebase configuration setup.

Maybe you should go through the tutorial again. https://docs.parseplatform.org/tutorials/android-push-notifications/
   To verify that you doing everything fine. As your code is clean, I can't figure out what is went wrong